# Adding field to custom module admin section in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created custom module with module creator,and it's appearing alright,now that I want to add a new field in it,somehow i can't do that.I have added the following lines to the file **Form.php** located in **Adminhtml/Modulename/Edit/Tab** :

```
$fieldset->addField('titlenew', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('test')->__('Title New'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'titlenew',
  ));
```

The field is appearing,but the data not getting saved.Help required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a new column to the table associated tot the entity you are editing.
Name it the same as the field `titlenew`. And clear the cache.
Even if the cache is disabled ZF cached the tables schema.

Comment: +1 for clearing the cache, even if it's disabled. That was the issue for me. I leave caching off on my dev box, so I didn't think to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a upgrade script to add a new column in the db table take a look @

[Magento – Install, install upgrade, data and data upgrade scripts](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/)

[Magento for Developers: Part 6 - Magento Setup Resources](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources)

Then  clear cache as suggested by @Marius

Answer (score 0):

change titlenew to titlenew2 and label 'Title New' to Title New2

```
$fieldset->addField('titlenew2', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('test')->__('Title New2'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'titlenew2',
  ));
```